# Submitting Multiple Checkboxes Values to Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox

I'm quite new to PHP and I'm looking for a way to submit a Value of Multiple Checkboxes into a Database! Right now I have managed to get the Checkboxes to display as Checked if the the Value in the Database = 1 otherwise it will be unchecked.

Below is the current code that I have.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_achievements_xbox WHERE user_id = '$userID' && game_id = '$gameID' ORDER BY achievement_id ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   // Start looping table row
    $userID = $row['user_id'];
    $gameID = $row['game_id'];
    $achievementID = $row['achievement_id'];
    $achievementName = $row['achievement_name'];
    $achievementDescription = $row['achievement_description'];
    $achievementValue = $row['achievement_value'];

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_achievements_xbox WHERE user_id = '$userID' && game_id = '$gameID' && achievement_id = '$achievementID'");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
    $achievement_locked = $row2['achievement_locked'];

    if($achievement_locked == "0")
    {
        $checked = 'checked="checked"';
    }
    else
    {
        $checked = "";
    }
?>
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
        <td> <img src="images/achievements/<?php echo $gameID; ?>/<?php echo $achievementID; ?>.jpg" /> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $achievementName; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $achievementDescription; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $achievementValue; ?> </td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="0" <?php echo $checked ?> /> </td>
    </tr>

<?php
} // end of while loop
?>
```

I was thinking about trying to do it via isset but I don't want a looped Submit button I can't seem to find how to wrap the Checkbox in a form for that but when I tested it quickly that way every value in "achievement_locked" in my Database became 0 when I only want the selected Checkboxes to change to 0 if checked or 1 if not!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This will help. http://corpocrat.com/2009/05/24/how-to-store-and-retreive-checkbox-value-in-mysql-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

This is one example. GEt the understanding. I have not escaped the POST variables. Make sure you do.

HTML File:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
  <p>
    <input name="colors[]" type="checkbox" id="colors[]" value="0">
    Red 
    <input name="colors[]" type="checkbox" id="colors[]" value="0">
    Blue 
    <input name="colors[]" type="checkbox" id="colors[]" value="0">
    Green</p>
  <p> 
    <input name="colors[]" type="checkbox" id="colors[]" value="0">
    Yellow 
    <input name="colors[]" type="checkbox" id="colors[]" value="0">
    Brown </p>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is what your php file should have.

```
<?php

$colors = $_POST['colors'];

$red = isset($colors[0]) ? 1 : 0;
$blue = isset($colors[1]) ? 1 : 0;
$green = isset($colors[2]) ? 1 : 0;
$yellow = isset($colors[3]) ? 1 : 0;
$brown =isset($colors[4]) ? 1 : 0;



// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (red,blue,green,yellow,brown) VALUES (:red,:blue,:green,:yellow,:brown)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':red'=>$red,
                    ':blue'=>$blue,
                    ':green'=>$green,
                    ':yellow'=>$yellow,
                  ':brown'=>$brown));
?>
```